# Install 2 Electrum wallets in a same computer

Tags: electrum

I have an Electrum Wallet in my computer, and I'd like to transfer my BTC to another Electrum Wallet, with a new seed and new adresses.

Is it possible to have 2 Electrum Wallets in a same computer? If so, how can I install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have 2 Electrum Wallets in a same computer? If so,
>   how can I install it?

You able to have as many wallets as you want. You dont need install electrum twice, all you need it is create new wallet.

I assume you already have a wallet with password. 
Run electrum and choose your wallet from the dialog:

[image]

Save that wallet somewhere in other place, and create another one with a new seed and new adresses. Then send from one to other.